# Adding Icons using CSS

Tags: html, css, icons

I am learning how to add Icons to my HTML and there is an example of it from W3 Schools like this :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Which is pretty much to link the stylesheet and be able to enter the icons from Font awesome page. However I do not like the messy way of adding it directly to the HTML . Is there an easier way for beginners to add Icons to the actual CSS instead of the body directly ?

Thank you ,

Comment: Your question isn't clear since you didn't post the example you mentioned. There are several ways to get icons shown. Its a question of circumstance and flavour.

Comment: I just updated the HTML

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to use fa icons

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<i class="fa fa-car"></i>
<i class="fa fa-car" style="font-size:48px;"></i>
<i class="fa fa-car" style="font-size:60px;color:red;"></i>

</body>
</html>
```